# Ribbon button value rule depending on statecode value

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm, ribbon, dynamics-crm-2013

I added a new custom button to quote form ribbon. This button should only appear, if the statecode is active ([Value: 1](http://msdynamicscrmblog.wordpress.com/2013/10/26/status-and-status-reason-values-in-dynamics-crm-2013/comment-page-1/)).

I created following CommandDefinition:

```
<CommandDefinition Id="mySolution.quote.Form.MyButton.Command">
    <EnableRules />
    <DisplayRules>
        <DisplayRule Id="mySolution.QuoteIsActive" />
    </DisplayRules>
    <Actions>
        <JavaScriptFunction FunctionName="myFunction" Library="$webresource:new_myLibrary" />
    </Actions>
</CommandDefinition>
```

And following DisplayRule:

```
<DisplayRule Id="mySolution.QuoteIsActive">
    <ValueRule Field="statecode" Value="1" Default="true" />
</DisplayRule>
```

But if I use this DisplayRule my button never appears. If I remove the rule from CommandDefinition the button is always visible.

I also tried to use 'Active' as value (as shown at the bottom of this [post](http://www.experts-exchange.com/Software/Microsoft_Applications/Microsoft_Dynamics/Q_26949090.html), with the same result.

What is the trick to define a rule depending on statecode? Or did I miss something?

Comment: Did you find a resolution to this problem?  I'm facing a similar issue, and I noticed that there's an OptionSetRule (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn481584.aspx), but it's marked for internal use only.

Answer (score 3):

Try using Status **text values** ("Open", "Draft", "Active", ect.) instead of number values. I have a similar case with Status Reasons. Hope it will help!

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't find anything to verify this, but display rules seem to have issues in the command bar. I had better luck using enable rules, and those actually act like you would expect display rules to act in the command bar. In other words, if a button in the command bar is disabled then it's not displayed. You can read about it in the [MSDN documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg334682.aspx#Anchor_0).

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem here is that your **EnableRules** is empty. 
However, are you doing that modifications by hand?
If so, [use CRM 2011 Visual Ribbon Editor](http://crmvisualribbonedit.codeplex.com/), this tool will do almost all job for you.

Comment: I this this is not the problem. If I remove the display rule the button appears. And I am doing that modification by hand. We had bad experience with using ribbon editors.

Comment: If u have a Test organization I would recommend you to do that with the tool and see how the Fetch.xml will look like.

Answer (score 0):

I think that your problem is that Statecode should be 0, not 1. Do a sql query on statecode and statecodename (use FilteredView).

Answer (score 0):

Just add simple .js script for updating ribbon. Ribbon updates only on page load. Thats why your button became always unvisible. Here is code sample:

```
function refreshRibbonOnChange()
{
   Xrm.Page.ui.refreshRibbon();
}
```

Then add web resource and attach it to button click. Simple!